# Do feats that affect spells like Spell Focus apply to Spell Like Abilities?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats

If you have a spell-Like ability that allows you to cast a spell, are feats and abilities that would modify the spell if it was cast normally apply? For example if you gained [Burning Hands](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burning-hands/) as a Spell-Like ability would that gain the benefit of [spell focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus/)?

Comment: Note there are monster feats that specifically enhance SLAs,  like https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/empower-spell-like-ability/

Comment: The question was more applying to standard feats rather than ones that mention SLA's by name. The FAQ explicitly calls out that Augment Summoning applies to the Summoner's SLA's but the general consensus is that feats that affect spells do not translate to their SLA equilivent so I was trying to reconcile that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Some *Pathfinder* developers apply some game elements to [spell-like abilities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Spell-Like_Abilities_Sp) as if they were actual spells

While the rules seem pretty clear about spell-like abilities and spells being different, *Pathfinder* developers seem to operate under the assumption that there's some overlap. For example, [Owen K.C. Stephenson](https://paizo.com/people/OwenKCStephens) in a 2010 Paizo Messagboard [thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kjnz?Summoner-Class-and-Augment-Summoning#10), in part, writes:

> When you add a metamagic feat to a spell-like ability, you end up having to use a spell-like slot one or more levels higher. Since there is no such thing as a spell-like slot, you can't use your metamagic enhanced spell-like ability. (If you add metamagic feats with a +0 level modifier from some other source, they'd work fine with spell-like abilities).
>
> [Augment Summoning](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/augment-summoning/), however, along with [Spell Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-focus/), [Spell Penetration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-penetration/) and the greater versions of same, has no need for a spell-like slot to function. Thus they work just fine with spell-like abilities in addition to spells. [Links added.]

I suspect that this is why the feat **Augment Summoning** works with the summoner class feature [***summon monster I***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoneR/#Summon_Monster_I_Sp), a spell-like ability, despite the Augment Summoning feat saying that it affects "[e]ach creature you conjure with any summon spell," never mentioning spell-like abilities. Nonetheless, according to this telegraphic [FAQ entry](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rbq) and according to this equally telegraphic [post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2k75q?Round-2-Rules-Questions#14) by *Pathfinder* Director of Game Design [**Jason Bulmahn**](https://paizo.com/people/JasonBulmahn), the feat *does* affect that spell-like ability. This line of thought would likewise explain why the [**leanan sidhe**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/leanan-sidhe/), for example, can take and benefit from the feat **Spell Focus** despite her not actually casting spells.

(It's likely due to this assumption that the *FAQ* also must then take on how spell-like abilities interact with [item creation feats](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qp0), [metamagic feats](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ofk), [metamagic rods](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9ofl), and—most tellingly for our purposes—[prerequisites](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qow).)

To address the question's example more precisely, an [ifrit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit/) can employ 1/day the spell-like ability [*burning hands*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burning-hands). I suspect a typical Paizo *Pathfinder* developer would rule that the ifrit's feat Spell Focus (evocation) applies to that spell-like ability, but that the ifrit typically couldn't apply to that spell-like ability the feat [Empower Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/empower-spell-metamagic/).

To be clear: I don't agree with this reading of the rules, and I certainly won't *defend* it, but readers should be aware that it exists.

---

***Note:** If you clicked this answer's title's [link](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Spell-Like_Abilities_Sp), you were taken to the section **Magic** in the subsection **Special Abilities** where there's a definition of **Spell-like Abilities**. If you were actually* looking for information *about spell-like abilities—instead of hunting for every mention in the* Pathfinder SRD *of* spell-like ability—, *that definition probably wasn't your [first](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/), [second](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/?/#Spell-Like_Abilities_Sp), or even [third](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#Spell-Like_Abilities_Sp) destination, but it's the* only *definition that includes this statement: "Usually, a spell-like ability works just like the spell of that name." I suspect that the* Pathfinder *developers' understanding of how spell-like abilities work grew from that statement to blur the stark line between spell-like abilities and spells that was drawn by the game's antecedent* Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 *and its* [FAQ](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610) *entry (44) on the same subject that makes pretty much the exact opposite ruling.*

Answer (score 7):

### Spell-like abilities are not spells

This is explained under spell-like abilities (Bestiary, p. 304).

> Spell-like abilities are magical and work just like spells (**though they are not spells** and so have no verbal, somatic, focus, or material components)

The explanation then goes on to explain *in which ways* spell-like abilities behave like spells

> It is possible to attempt a concentration check to use a spell-like ability defensively and avoid provoking attacks of opportunity, j**ust as when casting a spell**. A spell-like ability can be disrupted **just as a spell** can be. Spell-like abilities cannot be used to counterspell, nor can they be counterspelled.

In that list of things, there is no mention about feats applying to spell-like abilities, just as they would to spells.

The Spell Focus feat states:

> Any **spells** you cast of that school are more difficult to resist.

It only applies to *spells*. So spell-like abilities would not benefit from it.

Comment: Yeah, the key thing with spell-like abilities is, they are each (usually) very much *like* some spell, that is, having *fireball* as a spell-like ability allows you to generate an effect nearly identical to casting the *fireball* spell in terms of what it does. But as a class of abilities, spell-like abilities aren’t very *like* spells at all.