# How can Kineticists improve the DC of their wild talents?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, saving-throw, kineticist

How can Kineticists improve the DC of their wild talents? Since wild talents are considered spell-like abilities (with effective spell levels) or supernatural, would Spell Focus feat chains work?

Answer (score 5):

### Increasing your Constitution

Since the DC of Wild Talents is con-based for a kineticist, increasing your con would increase the DC.

---

### About Spell Focus

[Spell Focus works on SLAs.](https://www.aonprd.com/MythicMonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Leanan%20Sidhe) (See also [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/203976/8610))

However, there is a catch to [Spell Focus](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Focus):

> Add +1 to the Difficulty Class for all saving throws against spells from the *school of magic* you select.

Most wild talents do not have a school of magic (such as transmutation or conjuration) associated with them, which means that spell focus does not increase their DCs.

Answer (score 2):

Building from [willuwontu's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206038/81503) you could take [**Elemental Focus**](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elemental%20Focus) instead of Spell Focus.

> Choose one energy type (acid, cold, electricity, or fire). Add +1 to the Difficulty Class for all saving throws against spells that deal damage of the energy type you select.

Assuming that your Kineticist uses one of those elements, your damage dealing Wild Talents would have their DCs increased by both Elemental Focus and Greater Elemental Focus.

Comment: Sadly I can't since my elements are void and aether.